# How to duplicate Product Price and insert next to configurable options?

Tags: pricing

I'm trying to display pricing again on the product page right above my configurable product options. How can I go about doing that? I've tried to copy the code on view.phtml to my wrapper.phtml and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at wrapper.phtml, I don't think it is a product block and so the same code would not work here.

Perhaps if you try editing the appropriate type file (template/catalog/product/view/options/type/*.phtml) the same code as in your view.phtml will work

Comment: I have a configurable.phtml ?

Comment: I would guess it might work in  (template/catalog/product/view/type/options) configurable.phtml. Without seeing your site or code it is a bit of a guess.